# Does css support percent class name

Tags: css

I have a div with this class:

```
<div class="hero-section width-80%"> A Hero Image </div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.width-80%{
max-width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

Does a percent sign allowed to use in class value ? If I want to use any percent class with "%" symbol, How can I use a percent sign in css?

Comment: [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) - It isn't valid, but you can seemingly escape it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'd have to [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) it in your selector:

```css
.width-80\% {
  max-width: 80%;
  
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-section width-80%">A Hero Image</div>
```

[But it is not valid by the CSS specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) (as commented by [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%c3%81lvaro-gonz%c3%a1lez))